# How to check length of string and return a value with leading zero's

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, string-formatting

Question is how can I check the lenght of my string filenum, this string will change so for example it could be '1' how can I add 4 leading zeros onto the '1' making filenum = '00001' and so on lets say filenum = '21' and add three leading zero's filenum ='00021' I always want file num to have a length of 5. Also after I get the new value how can I use that value for my path's. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far but I get this error(error C2665: 'basic_string< char,struct std::char_traits, class std::allocator >::basic_string

```
void CJunkView::OnCadkeyButton() 

{ 

   CString dbdir15 = "Dir15";
   CString dbdir14 = "Dir14";
   std::string filenum = m_csFileName;
  //CString fileName3 = "15001.prt";
   CString dbyear = m_csDatabaseYear;

   if(filenum.length() < 1)
   {
      std::string filenums = std::string(5 - filenum.length(), "0") + filenum;
   }
   else if(filenum.length() < 2)
  {
      std::string filenums = std::string(4 - filenum.length(), "0") + filenum;

  }
  else if(filenum.length() < 3)
  {
     std::string filenums = std::string(3 - filenum.length(), "0") + filenum;
  }
  else if(filenum.length() < 4)
  {
     std::string filenums = std::string(2 - filenum.length(), "0") + filenum;
  }
  else if(filenum.length() < 5)
  {
      std::string filenums = std::string(1 - filenum.length(), "0") + filenum;
  }


    if(m_csDatabaseYear == "15")
    {
      CString fileToOpen = "\"\\\\CARBDATA\\VOL1\\Docs\\PREFORM\\15T\\" + dbdir15 +"\\" + filenum + "\"";
      CString exePath = "\"C:\\CK19\\Ckwin.exe\"";
      CString cmd = "start " + exePath + ", " + fileToOpen;
      system (cmd.GetBuffer(cmd.GetLength() + 1));
      //PrintMessage("File Found 2015");
    }

     //file not found tell user file not found.

    else if(m_csDatabaseYear == "14")
    {
      CString fileToOpen = "\"\\\\CARBDATA\\VOL1\\Docs\\PREFORM\\14T\\" + dbdir14 +"\\" + filenum + "\"";
      CString exePath = "\"C:\\CK19\\Ckwin.exe\"";
      CString cmd = "start " + exePath + ", " + fileToOpen;
      system (cmd.GetBuffer(cmd.GetLength() + 1));
      //PrintMessage("File Found 2015");
    }
    else
    {

      PrintMessage("File Not Found");
    }
```

}

Comment: That error message doesn't seem quite complete. When showing error message please include the *complete* and also unedited error output.

Comment: Why are you mixing `mfc`'s `CString` and standard C++ `std::string` in this function? Generally you would want to stick with one or the other unless you need to go from `mfc` code into something that uses standard strings (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a `std::string` constructor that does not exist.  The constructor you want to call expects a single `char` as input, but you are passing it a `char*` string literal instead.  Also, your `if` statements are wrong anyway, and overkill. You only need 1 `if` to handle all of the cases. And you are not even using the `filenums` variables that you are creating, you should be adding the padding to `filenum` itself instead.

Try this:

```
std::string filenum = m_csFileName;
if (filenum.length() < 5)
    filenum = std::string(5 - filenum.length(), '0') + filenum;
```

Comment: Thank you all for you answers all of these worked for me! I do have a question which is more efficient !

Comment: I get this error when trying to use your answer "error C2679: binary '+' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_

Comment: There most certainly is such an operator defined: [std::operator+(std::basic_string)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+). Do you have `#include <string>` in your code?

Comment: yes @Remy Lebeau
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "junk.h"
#include <afxdao.h>
//#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "windows.h"
#include <shellapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"shell32.lib") 
static HWND hBut; 
#include "junkSet.h"
#include "junkDoc.h"
#include "junkView.h"
#define PUT_CPP_FILE 1
#include "PrintMessage.h" 
#include "ReadWriteInitials.h"

Comment: where the error is pointing it looks like its in this part when I try to call the newly formatted filenum       CString fileToOpen = "\"\\\\CARBDATA\\VOL1\\Docs\\PREFORM\\14T\\" + dbdir14 +"\\" + filenum + "\"";

Comment: You are concatenating `CString` and `std::string` objects together in the same statement. That will not work. The result of the first `+` is a `CString`  (because `dbdir14` is a `CString`) so all subsequent `+` in the statement will create `CString` objects. `CString` does not have an `operator+` that accepts a `std::string` as input, and vice versa. You will have to use `filenum.c_str()` in this situation: `CString fileToOpen = "\"\\\\CARBDATA\\VOL1\\Docs\\PREFORM\\14T\\" + dbdir14 +"\\" + filenum.c_str() + "\""; `

Comment: thank you that did it and thank you for all of your help I will accept yours as the answer instead. @Remy Lebeau

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `CString` class (as your post seems marked with `"visual-c++"` and you seem to already use `CString` in your code - perhaps at the Win32 layer boundary), you can use the [**`CString::Format()`** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6.aspx).

In particular, you can pass a `%05d` string format specifier, meaning that you want a 5-digit padding:

```
int n = 1; // or whatever...
CString paddedNum;
paddedNum.Format(L"%05d", n);

// paddedNum contains "00001"
```

Then, you can build your full path/filename, simply using CString's `operator+`, to concatenate several substrings.

Or you could still use `CString::Format()`, to specify a more complex string format for the full path/filename.

You can use the [`printf()` format specification syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) for `CString::Format()`.

Comment: don't use non-standard functionality if you want a portable code.

Comment: @Walter: To me, the use of CString is just fine in those parts of code at the Win32 boundary. CString has several non-standard convenient methods useful at that boundary level, for example loading string from resources, etc. Moreover, the OP's existing code base is clearly already using CString in abundance.

Answer (score 2):

Could easily be done with e.g. [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and the normal [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << filenum;
std::cout << os.str() << '\n';  // Get the string in the stream and output it
```

If `filenum` is e.g. `"1"` then the output of the above three lines should be

```
00001
```

Comment: So then I could just use os as my filenum in my file path part? @Joachim Pileborg